# how to use method implemented in a view from another view : backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

i want to call a method from view#1 which is already implemented in different view (view#2)..
how to achieve this in a nice n simple way.. using backbonejs.

```
App.Views.view1 = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
       'click .someclass1' : 'custom_method_1',
         },

        custom_method_1:function(e){

         //now this method calls another method which is implemented in different view
         custom_method_2();
    },
});


 App.Views.view2 = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
       'click .someclass2' : 'custom_method_2',
         },

   //// this method needs to be called from view1 also
        custom_method_2:function(e){

    },
});
```

Comment: You may put common method outside of your View component.

Comment: ya that's how m doin it for now... but i want to do it the backbone way..
there is something called backbone eventbus.. i guess thats the solution for problem like this.. 
n now m expecting someone to explain/demo using eventbus or any other backbone solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search how to use the eventbus, you can do it like this:

```
// you can name the event 'custom_method_2' as you want
Backbone.Events.on('custom_method_2', App.Views.view2.custom_method_2);
```

Now you are listening to the event `custom_method_2` on the Object `Backbone.Events` that you can consider as your eventsbus.

Then in `view1`:

```
custom_method_1:function(e){

     //now this method calls another method which is implemented in different view
     // custom_method_2();
     Backbone.Events.trigger('custom_method_2', e);
},
```